# If I have a single nonclustered index on a table, will the number of columns I include change the slow down when writing to it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, indexing

On the exact same table, if I was to put one index on it, either:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_single ON MyTable (uid asc) include (columnone)
```

or:

```
CREATE INDEX ix_multi ON MyTable (uid asc) include (
    columnone,
    columntwo,
    columnthree,
    ....
    columnX
)
```

Would the second index cause an even greater lag on how long it takes to write to the table than the first one? And why?

Comment: mysql or sql-server?

Comment: Well, logically, if you have to write more data to the disk, it'll probably take longer... Doubt it'll be noticeable in most circumstances, though. Why d'you ask?

Comment: I removed the mysql tag because it does not support `include`.

Comment: Hi, if my answer was usefull it would be very kind of you to vote it up and/or mark it as accepted, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Included columns will need more diskspace as well as time on data manipulation...

If there is a clustered index on this table too (ideally on a implicitly sorted column like an IDENTITY column to avoid fragmentation) this will serve as fast lookup on all columns (but you must create the clustered index before the other one...)

To include columns into an index is a usefull approach in extremely performance related issues only...